# How do I fix this error message "The parameters (number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues."?

Tags: google-sheets

Need assistance on why I am unable to clear this error message  "The parameters (number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues."

```
function Submit() {
      var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Vehicle Sale Form"); //Form Sheet
      var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sales Log"); //Data Sheet
      var datasheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Vehicle Purchased"); //Data Sheet 2
    
      var ratesData = datasheet2.getRange(4, 3, datasheet2.getLastRow()-3, 4).getValues();
      var searchValue = formSS.getRange("C23").getValue();
      var matchRow = ratesData.find(r => r[0] == searchValue);
    
      var match = matchRow ? matchRow[2] : null;
    
    datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow(), 7, 1, 1).setValues(match);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Range.setValues()` expects a 2D array of values, but `match` is a single value rather than an array. To make it work, use `Range.setValue()`, like this:

```
    datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow(), 7).setValue(match);
```

Comment: that works nicely... Thank you for clearing that up.